# I suggest to merge the tags "this" and "this-pointer" but havn't enough reputation yet

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I am not sure if this kind of suggestion fits here, if not please tell me a better place. On Stackoverflow, the tags [this](/questions/tagged/this) and [this-pointer](/questions/tagged/this-pointer) might be synonyms.

Is there a reason for them not to be? If not, could someone please merge them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[this](/questions/tagged/this) and [this-pointer](/questions/tagged/this-pointer) are not the same.

[this](/questions/tagged/this) has the following wiki

> Keyword that refers to the current class instance / object **in most object-oriented programming languages**.

[this-pointer](/questions/tagged/this-pointer) has the wiki

> This Pointer is a compiler generated pointer during a function call pointing to the object upon which that function gets called.

which is **specific for programming languages using pointer arithmetic** like `C++`.